# Earlier Release of Visual Studio 2012 Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsix, downgrade

Is there anyway to downloangrade visual studio extensions. Visual Studio Extension keep the older version or not. if not where can i find the older version of extensions.

i'm trying to downgrade [VS10X Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2) to 3.68 or 3.67 version

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have downloaded the visx file with the preovious version this is not possible via VS gallery. Contact the package owner - btw, release 3.69 is now available.

Comment: hi ErikEJ thanks for the response. i'm just wondered is there have cache files on VS app data or something!!